# How to connect hive server using node js

Tags: node.js, hadoop, hive

I am trying to connect Hive using jshs2 but not able establish a connection. Is 
it right  way to coonect hive using this npm. My source code is as follows:

```
const jshs2 = require('jshs2');
const options = {};
options.auth = 'NOSASL';
options.host = 'host name';
options.port = '10000';
options.username = 'user name';
options.password = 'password';
options.hiveType = 2;
const hiveConfig = new Configuration(options);
const idl = new IDLContainer();
async function main() {
        await idl.initialize(hiveConfig);
        const connection = await new HiveConnection(hiveConfig, idl);
        const cursor = await connection.connect();
        const res = await cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 10');
        if (res.hasResultSet) {
            const fetchResult = await cursor.fetchBlock();
            fetchResult.rows.forEach((row) => {
                console.log(row);
            });
        }
        cursor.close();
        connection.close();
}
main().then(() => {
        console.log('Finished.');
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? and what version of node you are using?

Comment: node js version is v10.0.0.0 and not able to establish connection means on connection.connect() line don't get any response.

Comment: Are you using Hiveserver or Hiveserver2?

Comment: hiveserver2 and hive.server2.authentication is set as default value i.e SASL. and we don't want to change that configuration on server without that we need to connect hive server using node js. if not then please suggest other solution.

Comment: Ok. Please share the Error stack as well as the configuration object(Your code).

Comment: const jshs2 = require('jshs2');
const options = {};

options.auth = 'NOSASL'; 
options.host = 'host name'; 
options.port = '10000'; 
options.username = 'user name';
options.password = 'password';
options.hiveType = 2;

Comment: await idl.initialize(hiveConfig);
    const connection = await new HiveConnection(hiveConfig, idl);
    const cursor = await connection.connect();
    const res = await cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 10');

    if (res.hasResultSet) {
        const fetchResult = await cursor.fetchBlock();
        fetchResult.rows.forEach((row) => {
            console.log(row);
        });
    }

Comment: Please edit your question and share relevant code/file(s). Not like this.

Comment: any update on my question?

Comment: How you got to know that your hiveType is 2? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Sookie we have the hiver server2 is hosted hence we provide hiveType =2 in option that's it.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in comments you use SASL auth, but the author of [jshs2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshs2) mentioned that  the lib doesn't support SASL authentication ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshs2#important))

You may use [java jdbc](https://mapr.com/support/s/article/Connect-Node-js-JDBC-application-to-Hiveserver2?language=en_US) or [hive-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hive-driver) to connect Hive using SASL in nodejs

```js
const hive = require('hive-driver');
const { TCLIService, TCLIService_types } = hive.thrift;
const client = new hive.HiveClient(
    TCLIService,
    TCLIService_types
);
const utils = new hive.HiveUtils(
    TCLIService_types
);
 
client.connect(
    {
        host: 'host name',
        port: 10000
    },
    new hive.connections.TcpConnection(),
    new hive.auth.PlainTcpAuthentication({
     username: 'user name',
     password: 'password'
    })
).then(async client => {
    const session = await client.openSession({
        client_protocol: TCLIService_types.TProtocolVersion.HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V10
    });
    const operation = await session.executeStatement(
        'SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 10'
    );
    await utils.waitUntilReady(operation, false, () => {});
    await utils.fetchAll(operation);

    console.log(
        utils.getResult(selectDataOperation).getValue()
    );

    await operation.close();
    await session.close();
});
```

Comment: The `jdbc` approach work for me. It can handle those not standard hive product, like `Transwarp Inceptor`